# Why reading Floating point number from file gives rounded output?

Tags: c++

i have a file and two inputs are shown below:

> 34.800287000  0.077352000

i'm reading from a file(by getline then define stringstream) and saving it in my class variables which are both defined **double**. However
when i check my variables i see that:

> 34.8003 0.077352

**EDIT:** i'm using cout to check my variables.

why is that ?

thanks.

Comment: How are you checking your variables?  Cout will automatically round before outputting

Comment: Keep in mind that a `double` *cannot* contain `34.800287000`. A `double` uses a fixed-with binary representation (often 64 bits), not a variable-length decimal representation. `std::ifstream` did an approximate conversion from decimal and `std::cout` will give you a decimal approximation; both are generally imprecise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard IO streams classes have a limit to their precision that can be customized at runtime.  By default I believe it's six places, which matches the output you're getting above.  If you want to increase the precision, you can use the `setprecision` stream manipulator:

```
double myValue = /* ... */
cout << setprecision(12) << myValue << endl; // Print with higher precision
```

The `setprecision` manipulator is defined in `<iomanip>` and when used once will change the behavior of `cout` to print at higher precision for the rest of the program, which in your case may be helpful.  Try this out and see if your numbers really are losing precision.

Comment: is there a way to make setprecision() to be used not only one variable as you mentioned but for every variable of my program.is this will give what i want :cout << setprecision(12);

Comment: I believe what you'll find is that if you set precision on the output stream (cout) it will maintain that for life of the stream or until set to something else. Experiment.

Answer (score 2):

when printing with cout, your numbers will be rounded.  If you want to see more decimals, use `std::setprecision` from header `iomanip`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/